# Django-allauth with multiple profile models

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a django project in which there are multiple profile models, each having a foreign key to the User model. It uses `django-allauth` for registration.

Currently, when registering using a social account, the user registers, a User and a socialaccount is created, then the user is redirected to a form to fill out, depending on what profile type s/he chose earlier, and after filling out that form is the correct profile type created.

I'd like it if the user, socialaccount and profile type instances are created in the same step, that is after the user fills out the profile specific form. Is there anyway I can do this without changing `allauth's` code? It wouldn't be too hard to do this by modifying allauth, but I'd rather not maintain a custom copy of a 3rd party app if it can be helped.

Using a custom adapter is out, because it does not have access to the request.

Comment: If the answer was satisfactory, it would help if you accept it. If not, please comment, so we can figure out the proper answer.

Comment: Oh sorry. Have been a little busy and replying to the answer slipped out of my mind

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the `allauth.account.signals.user_signed_up` signal, which is triggered just after the user (social or normal) signs up. You can do your stuff with your account there:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def do_stuff_after_sign_up(sender, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs['request']
    user = kwargs['user']
    # Do your stuff with the user
    user.save()
```

From [django-allauth repo](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/signals.py):

```
# Typically followed by `user_logged_in` (unless, e-mail verification kicks in)
user_signed_up = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
```

To learn how to use signals in django, read [the official documentation about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/).

I hope it helps you!

### EDIT

I'm glad you found your way through your problem, but since middlewares are loaded always, I would suggest using the approach I proposed. The `socialaccount` module from `django-allauth` also provide [signals](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/signals.py). Among them, you can find the `allauth.socialaccount.signals.social_account_added`:

```
# Sent after a user connects a social account to a his local account.
social_account_added = Signal(providing_args=["request", "sociallogin"])
```

With a handler similar to the previously written, you can check the user model for the required fields, and then call the [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut, or return an [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) object that redirects to the view that shows/handle your form.

Comment: Well this wouldn't work for us, as we need the user to fill up a form after a social sign up. What we've done is created a custom middleware that redirects any user who hasn't filled up that form to the form page.

Comment: @elssar: I edited the answer, I hope it to be useful. Regards.

Comment: thanks for the edit. Redirecting the user to the appropriate form wasn't the problem. The problem was what happens if they don't fill out that form. They could still login and browse around the site. We didn't want users with incomplete profiles to do that.

Comment: That justify loading the middleware. In that case, I would also use your approach.

Comment: @elssar would you mind sharing your custom middleware? We're up against the same problem (multiple profile models) and would love to see how you did it. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewWidgery apologies, I've forgotten what exactly I did, and since I've switched jobs, I don't have access to the code.

Comment: @AndrewWidgery actually, I think we dispensed of the custom middleware, and ensured that the user model isn't saved until the user fills our the profile form. Unfortunately all I remember is I subclassed the socialaccount adapter and did something there. Can try and figure out what I did if I have time during the weekend