# Create UserProfile Model after User signed up using allauth Django

Tags: django, user-profile, django-allauth

I have a django project in which there is a UserProfile having a OneToOne to the User model. It uses django-allauth for registration.

I am accepting registration via account and social account. Upon signing up, i want the user to be redirected to a page to create the UserProfile for that user account.

How could i do that ?

I have read, there is 1 signal called user_signed_up, can it be used to redirect the user to certain page ? I tried this code below, but it doesn't redirect me to the page i wanted.

```
@receiver(user_signed_up, dispatch_uid="some.unique.string.id.for.allauth.user_signed_up")
def do_stuff_after_sign_up(sender, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs['request']
    user = kwargs['user']
    return redirect ('/test/')
```

any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: I hope that is not the indentation of your actual code

Comment: hehe, oops i just copy and pasted it. thanks for the comment @yuvi

Comment: regarding your question, does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295603/decide-where-to-go-to-after-connecting-with-django-allauth

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503210/805427) should help.

Comment: Hi @yuvi, thanks but not suitable actually. cause i want the profile page only accessed at the first time they signed up not everytime they logged in :)

Comment: hi @elssar,can i go to a certain view after receiving the user_signed_up signal ?

Comment: No, for that you will have to use the method that @yuvi linked. Just check whether the user has a profile or not in the view and take it from there. Or even better, use a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but I hope future readers would find it helpful. :)

You need to raise an  `ImmediateHttpResponse` like this:

```
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

@receiver(user_signed_up, dispatch_uid="some.unique.string.id.for.allauth.user_signed_up") 
def do_stuff_after_sign_up(sender, **kwargs): 
    request = kwargs['request'] 
    user = kwargs['user'] 
    raise ImmediateHttpResponse(render(request, 'you_custom_profile.html', {'user': user}))
```