# Importing user data into django-allauth from a legacy database

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I have a web application that is currently written in rather messy PHP with a messy database that I'm in the process of migrating to Django. I have set it up in my project as a legacy database and have generated models using inspectdb, so I think I can fairly easily write a script to translate old database to new, but I'm not sure how to tackle the user side.

Originally the app had some sort of Facebook integration, but this broke a few years ago when Facebook changed their side. The current users table has Facebook IDs for some users, but no other Facebook data (some users have also set email addresses and local passwords too).

I have a basic install of django-allauth with the Facebook integration set up and working, so can I import all of the users somehow? Those with the local alternative login-credentials (whether with a Facebook ID or not) are probably more important than the ones that only have a Facebook ID, so should I just use the standard Django create user methods and let users re-enable their own Facebook integration at a later time?

Comment: If the FB data is years of and you don't actually have stored some access tokens from Facebook, you can as well disregard all the FB IDs because you can't use them anyway for login purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much.

I wondered if I could put them into the system though so that if they ever re-registered, then their Facebook ID would allow their data to be retrieved.

Comment: Only with the FB ID you're not able to get any data from FB other than the standard profile info. For everything else you'll need an Access Token (which expires after 60 days). There's nothing against keeping the FB ID for any further reference.

Comment: I've had a better thought, I think I'm going to hook into [the signals that allauth sends on user creation/signup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963323/django-allauth-with-multiple-profile-models/18503210#18503210) and then pull in the user's old data if any exists. I can easily keep the legacy database around to do this.